# HTML parsing / checking for certain value of certain attribute of certain tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-parsing, zooming

How can I, with JavaScript, check if a webpage has any of the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1" />

<meta name="viewport" content="maximum-scale=1" />

<meta name="viewport" content="maximum-scale=1.0" />

<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no" />
```

and if any of this is in the source, then run certain JavaScript code like in the suite of an if-condition.

Basically what I am trying to do is check if zooming is disabled in anyway and if so, execute certain code and if not the execute other code.

Comment: var nodes = $('meta[name=viewport]');
$(nodes).each(function(index, nodeValue){
 var content =  $(nodeValue).attr('content');// check nodeValue here
});

Comment: @VijayPatel can you explain how to check nodeValue for each of the elements in the index in an answer?

Comment: @Irfan Please check my post

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
function readViewportValues(){
    var metas = $('meta[name=viewport]');
    var properties = {};

    function isNumber(n) {
        return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
    }

    function readItem(index, text) {
        var parts = jQuery.trim(text).split(' ');
        console.log(parts);
        if (parts.length > 1) {
            $.each(parts, readItem);
        } else {
            parts = parts[0].split('=');
            var key = jQuery.trim(parts[0]),
                value = parts[1];
            value = isNumber(value) ? parseFloat(value) : value;
            properties[key] = value;
        }
    }

    metas.each(function () {
        var content = $(this).attr('content').split(',');
        $.each(content, readItem);
    });
    return properties;
}


// usage
var viewport = readViewportValues();
if (viewport['maximum-scale'] === 1){
    // do something
}
```

This will return an object with the found properties and you can query it..

Answer (score 0):

```
var nodes = $('meta[name=viewport]'); 
$(nodes).each(function(index, nodeValue){ 
     var content = $(nodeValue).attr('content');// check nodeValue here 
     // You will get values of content from each meta element here in content variable ex. "user-scalable=no"
     // so now based on these values you can so do any processing you want
});
```